# How to fix TemplateSyntaxError?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to render template, but it always get an TemplateSyntaxError error.

For solve this I tried to change construction. Instead

```html
{% if value %} 
-some action
{% else %} 
{% endif %}
```

I tried:

```html
{% if value_1 %}
- some action
{% endif %}
{% if value_2 %}
- some action
{% endif %}
```

But it didn't bring success, always the same error. I thought, that I made mistake with `'{'` or `'%'`, but I didn't found anything, that couldn't be properly.

Then I tried to find solve my problem, but all the problems that were considered had problems with the wrong syntax, like `'%{'` or `'{ %'`.

#### VIEW

```py
class HumanList(TemplateView):`

    def post(self, request):

        search_type = request.POST.get('type', False)
        search_object = request.POST.get('object', False)

        def separate(search_type, search_object):
        try:
            if search_type == 'name':
                return Human.objects.all().get(name__exact=search_object)
            if search_type == 'surname':
                return Human.objects.all().filter(name__contains=search_object)
            if search_type == 'company':
                return Human.objects.filter(company=search_object)
            if search_type == 'position':
                return Human.objects.filter(position=search_object)
            if search_type == 'language':
                return Human.objects.filter(language=search_object)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

        search_result = separate(search_type, search_object)

        if search_result:
            context = {
                'result': search_result,
                'searched': search_object,
            }
        else:
            context = {
                'empty': 'We couldn\'t find anything',
                'searched': search_object,
            }

        return render(request, 'result.html', context)
```

#### HTML TEMPLATE

```html
{% extends 'human_list.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h2>SEARCH FORM</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p>TYPE OF SEARCH</p>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="name">Name<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="surname">Surname<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="company">Company<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="position">Position<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="language">Language<br>

    <p>SEARCH REQUEST</p>
    <input type="text" name="object">
    <br><br>

    <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
</form>

<h2>SEARCH RESULT BY '{{searched}}'</h2>

{% if empty %}
<p style=" font-size: 32px; color: #CC3434;">{{empty}}</p>


{% else %}
<table border="1">
    <tr style="background: #f5dd5d; color: #4a4949">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Birth</td>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Language</td>
    </tr>
    {% for item in result %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.surname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.birth}}</td>
        <td>{{item.company}}</td>
        <td>{{item.position}}</td>
        <td>{{item.salary}}</td>
        <td>{{item.language}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

> TemplateSyntaxError at /lesson-six/human-list/ 
>   Unclosed tag on line 51: 'if'. Looking for one of: endif.

[image]

Comment: Your code worked for me. Can you share your human_list.html?

Comment: I tried to paste code here, but it says, that my code so long. I wrote it there -
https://anotepad.com/notes/jyyffnf
If it’s forbidden to do (means share link to other services) so, tell me that and tell me about alternative services please